# Pytorch second derivative returns None

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

I am unable to take a second derivative of the following function. When I want the second derivative with respect to u_s it works but with x_s it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong here?

```
def cost(xt, x_goal, u, Q, R):
        return (xt - x_goal).matmul(Q).matmul((xt - x_goal).transpose(0,1)) + u.matmul(R).matmul(u)

x_s = tr.tensor([ 0.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000], dtype=torch.float64,  requires_grad=True)
u_s = tr.tensor([-0.2749], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
c = cost(x_s, x_Goal, u_s, tr.tensor(Q), tr.tensor(R))

c
   output: 
   tensor([[4.0076]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)

Cu = grad(c, u_s, create_graph=True)[0]
Cu
   output:
   tensor([-0.0550], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<ThAddBackward>)

Cuu = grad(Cu, u_s, allow_unused=True)[0]
Cuu
   output:
   tensor([0.2000], dtype=torch.float64)

Cux = grad(Cu, x_s, allow_unused=True)
Cux
    output:
    (None,)
```

I am guessing the Cu itself is completely independent of x_s, but then the derivative should be zero at least, not None!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't done anything wrong.

Suppose I have variables `x`, `y`, and `z=f(y)`. If I compute z.backward() and then try to ask for the gradient with respect to x, I get `None`. For example,

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(1,requires_grad=True)
y = torch.randn(1,requires_grad=True)

z = y**2
z.backward()
print(y.grad) # Outputs some non-zero tensor
print(x.grad) # None
```

So what does this have to do with your attempt to compute the second derivative `Cux`? When you write `create_graph=True`, PyTorch keeps track of all the operations in the derivative computations which computed `Cu`, and since the derivatives themselves are made up of primitive operations, you can compute the gradient of the gradient, as you are doing. The problem here is that the gradient `Cu` never encounters the variable `x_s`, so effectively `Cu = f(u_s)`. This means that when you perform `Cu.backward()`, the computational graph for `Cu` never sees the variable `x_s`, so it's gradient type remains `None`, just like in the example above.